# How do you use a Facebook token to create a user in a Cognito User Pool, as depicted in AWS demo slides?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

Amazon Web Services [**provided the following slides**](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/add-end-user-signin-user-management-and-security-to-your-mobile-and-web-applications-with-amazon-cognito-78460889) to explain some of the features of AWS Cognito.

The slide below purports to show that you can get a Facebook token from Facebook login, and use that token to authenticate a user (or presumably create a new user) in a Cognito User Pool, which will in turn generate a new Cognito token for use in your applicaiton.

This sounds great.

The problem is that there are no code samples online that I can find that demonstrate **HOW** to do this.

So my question is, can anyone provide a clear code example or link to one that shows how to do this, preferably in Javascript, and even more preferably in Angular 2+ ?

[image: Cognito B2C Flow]